# Are there such things as Email Hooks?

Tags: ruby, email, gmail

After hearing about git commit hooks, I was thinking maybe there are such things as email hooks...

Is it possible for me to build a program that says "hey, you just received an email, now run this ruby script"?  Something like a GMail Web Hook.  Is there anything out there like that?  I mean I could build a cron thing that checked my email all the time, but maybe there's a more formal way.

Looking for an online email system to do this with, not say my Mac Mail.

Comment: [How to pull emails from GMail with Rails](http://www.papodenerd.net/how-to-pull-emails-from-gmail-to-rails-with-attachments/) and [reading emails using POP3 in Ruby](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1120) look like a start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [smtp2web](http://code.google.com/p/smtp2web/).  It basically consists of a SMTP daemon that maps incoming email to HTTP urls.  Then, you can run the server-side code of your choice on those URLs.  This is just one way to approach the problem.  It's designed particularly for use with Google App Engine.

You can either run your own instance, or just [sign up for mapping](http://www.smtp2web.com/addmapping?type=basic) (e.g. viatropos@smtp2web.com -> http://viatropos.com) and forward your gmail account to that.  Then, you would run a HTTP server at viatropos.com.

EDIT: I also found [Astrotrain](http://github.com/entp/astrotrain), which is similar but written in Ruby.

Comment: that looks awesome, but kind of sketchy due to it's very minimalistic nature :)

Comment: op, but it was [built by a google guy](http://almaer.com/blog/smtp2webcom-bridge-smtp-to-http-let-app-engine-accept-email), great!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends entirely on how you read your email. There are no user-accessible hooks in gmail, AFAIK, but you can pull gmail via POP3 and suck it through some mail processing system such as procmail.

Answer (score 1):

You can forward all incoming emails to a script. Normally a `.forward` file in your home directory that looks similar to this would be enough:

```
|/path/to/your/script
```

The script has to be executable.

Here's an [article](http://www.evolt.org/incoming_mail_and_php) about it. It's for PHP but it's the same for ruby. In the script you just need to read the STDIN to get the message.

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising, but its still in beta phase: 
https://zapier.com/zapbook/gmail/webhook/